# Existence of injective function in a manifold with special atlas

Tags: functions, smooth-manifolds

I am trying do the following question:

> Let $M$ be a $n$-dimensional smooth manifold that admits an atlas with only two charts. Show that there exists an injective smooth map $\varphi:M\to\mathbb{R}^{2(n+1)}$.

Well, I think unit partition helps, but I don't know how build a map with the earlier properties. Some hint?

Maybe the unity partition can be used to "glue" each coordinate map, but I don't know how this 
can be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: The key is that the manifold admits an atlas with only two charts.  What does that mean?  (In particular, you should write down what this means precisely.)

Comment: @AdamSaltz, I know that there exists two coordinates functions (in particular, diffeomorphism) such that the intersections is a diffeomorphism. Thus, in each chart is possible build a injective function, but I don't see how reach the solution

Comment: @AdamSaltz, do you have any hint?

Comment: @Adam: the meaning of an atlas having 2 charts is perfectly clear. If you know how to solve the problem, sketch a proof. Asking the OP to write down the definitions of concepts appearing in his question is rude and useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_i:U_i\to V_i\subset \mathbb R^n \;(i=1,2)$ be the two charts and let $\rho_i\;(i=1,2)$ be a partition of unity subordinate to the covering $(U_i)$.
The required map can then be taken as

> $$\phi=(\rho_1f_1,\rho_2f_2,\rho_1, \rho_2):M\hookrightarrow  \mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R \times      \mathbb R=\mathbb{R}^{2(n+1)}$$

[As usual $\rho_if_i:M\to \mathbb R^n$ is defined to be $0\in \mathbb R^n$  outside of $U_i$]

Injectivity of $\phi$ is shown as follows:
Suppose $\phi(m)=\phi(p)$.
  Since $\rho_1(m)+\rho_2(m)=1$, we must have   $\rho_1(m)\gt0$ (say).  But then $\rho_1(p)=\rho_1(m)\gt0$ too, which forces $m$ **and** $p$ to both be in $U_1$ and thus $m=p$ by the injectivity of  $f_1$.

**Note carefully**
The only way for a point $x\in M$ to satisfy  $\rho_1(x)\gt0$ is to be in $U_1$.
 But even this is not sufficient: there exist  points $y\in U_1$ with $\rho_1(y)=0$ : intuitively they are the points $y$ near the boundary $\partial U_1$ of $U_1$ .

Comment: Why $\rho_2(m)=\rho_1(p)$? I think you mean say $\rho_2(m)=\rho_2(p)$. Can you explain?

Comment: Dear Diego, that was an unfortunate  typo, now corrected: thanks for catching it.

Comment: No problem. By the way, beautiful solution.

Comment: A last question: Is this function well defined in the overlaps?

Comment: Dear Diego: yes the function is well defined everywhere with the convention alredy mentioned that $\rho_if_i:M\to \mathbb R^n$ is defined to be $0\in \mathbb R^n$  outside of $U_i$